# How do I double space a tkinter text widget without using extra newline characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, formatting

I have a tkinter Text widget in which I want to display the contents of a `dict` as a reference. I have no trouble configuring the style of each item, but I'm not pleased with the display because the lines are too close together for me to read comfortably. I want to "double space" the list, but I don't want to add extra newline characters, as this would get confusing and could potentially screw up how tagged areas are displayed. Specifically, I want to space the lines out so that the following criteria are met:

1. no vertical space above the first line of the listing
2. no vertical space below the last line of the listing
3. a consistent vertical spacing I specify between the lines of the listing
4. the text widget is wide enough to contain all the text without wrapping
5. each line of the listing is separated from the next by exactly one newline character
6. each key and each value is separately tagged and configurable

Here's my current code:

```
import tkinter

dictionary = {
  "test": "blue",
  "test2": "red",
  "test3": "green"
}
spacing = 30

root = tkinter.Tk()
text_widget = tkinter.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()
# "works" with this line, but don't want the side effect:
# text_widget.configure(width=5)

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
  text_widget.mark_set("begin", "insert")
  text_widget.insert("insert", key+": ", (key,))
  text_widget.insert("insert", value+"\n", (value,))
  text_widget.tag_configure(key, font="courier 12 normal")
  text_widget.tag_configure(value, foreground=value)

#corrected the starting index as per the comments
text_widget.tag_add("whole", "1.0", "end")
text_widget.tag_configure("whole", spacing2=spacing)

root.mainloop()
```

Though there are three `spacing` tag attributes that look like one of them should work for my case, none of them do. The `spacing2` attribute comes frustratingly close, but according to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm,

> spacing2
>
> This option specifies how much extra vertical space to add between displayed lines of text **when a logical line wraps.** Default is 0.

and this functionality doesn't seem particularly useful either, in my opinion.

Since I want to space all the text in the widget, it doesn't matter whether the solution is implemented at the tag level or widget-wide.

How can I put space between the lines of my listing according to the criteria given?

My expected output looks like this:

[image: Output]

`Python 3.8.2` `Tkinter 8.6`

Comment: You have to tag your text with `"whole"`, read [`insert(index, text, *tags)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.insert-method), and use `spacing1=`.

Comment: Note: `"0.0"` is not a valid index. The first character is `"1.0"`. `"0.0"` works, but only because tkinter will treat all indexes prior to `"1.0"` as if they were `"1.0"`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh, that's cool. Thank you for pointing this out. Either because I've missed it or because it's not out there, I hadn't seen any indication as to the minimum values for the indices.

Comment: It's documented as part of the Entry widget documentation. Line numbers start at 1, not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yyou need to use either `spacing1` on all but the first line, or `spacing3` on all but the last line. `spacing1` defines how much space to add above each line, and `spacing3` defines how much space to add below each line.

For example, this uses `spacing1` on all but the first line:

```
text_widget.tag_add("whole", "2.0", "end-1c")
text_widget.tag_configure("whole", spacing1=spacing)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. My spacing code now looks like `text_widget.tag_add("whole", "2.0", "%d.0" % (len(dictionary)+1))` `text_widget.tag_configure("whole", spacing1=spacing)` I didn't want to formally suggest an edit, but perhaps this should be the example code in the answer, since it meets the criteria listed in the question?

Comment: @EvanMessinger: that seems overly complicated. Why doesn't it work adding "whole"  all the way to the end rather than trying to calculate the index of the last line?

Comment: I could think of several situations. I could be building a page-rendering engine that needs to correctly deal with text nodes. Similarly, I could be building extensions to tkinter's methods to simplify them and want to make a `double_space` function whose spacing value was defined somewhere in user-set options. I think that "it looks neat" is plenty reason, though, and the code in your example doesn't produce output correct to the criteria in the question.

Comment: Why doesn't the code in my example produce what you want? Is it because of the space at the end? That's easily fixed. I've updated my answer to use `end-1c` instead of `end` which is the index of the last character on the last line.

Comment: That's a good point, and on second thought you're probably right anyway. Word processors double space by doing what your example does.